# String.IsNullOrEmpty() Check for Space

Tags: c#

What is needed to make `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` count whitespace strings as empty?

Eg. I want the following to return `true` instead of the usual `false`:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(" ");
```

Is there a better approach than:

```
 String.IsNullOrEmpty(" ".Trim());
```

*(Note that the original question asked what the return would be normally hence the unsympathetic comments, this has been replaced with a more sensible question).*

Comment: Have you tried it?  It'll return false, as the string you are passing is neither null nor the empty string.

Comment: Why don't you make simple test program and try it yourself?

Comment: Paddy: it will return false if I don't use Trim() I have tried it myself and that is why I am asking from your guys. From my point of view as we developer use trim very often, It must also use the trim function , that was what I though.

Comment: Sky Sanders: for what laziness, I have tried and now asking from your peoples. look at the answer given by João Angelo that was what I am looking for, but it was in next version.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

.NET 4.0 will introduce the method `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. Until then you'll need to use `Trim` if you want to deal with white space strings the same way you deal with empty strings.

For code not using .NET 4.0, a helper method to check for `null` or empty or whitespace strings can be implemented like this:

```
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Trim());
}
```

The `String.IsNullOrEmpty` will not perform any trimming and will just check if the string is a null reference or an empty string.

Comment: Hmm how will that behave if you do it as an extension method on String when .net 4.0 is out? ... or wait you can't write an extension to String only to instances of string, or am I wrong here?

Comment: @cyberzed, that could be a question all by itself. You're right about extensions methods applying only to instances of string. And since the new method on .NET 4.0 is a static method on the `String` class, no collision would happen.

Comment: Hehe, I came up with the answer myself just as i hit the "Add Comment" button so I decided to leave it as reference for other people :)

Answer (score 12):

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(" ")
```

...Returns False

```
String foo = null;
String.IsNullOrEmpty( foo.Trim())
```

...Throws an exception as `foo` is Null.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty( foo ) || foo.Trim() == String.Empty
```

...Returns true

Of course, you could implement it as an extension function:

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this string value)
    {
        return (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Trim()));
    }
}
```