# Easier way of writing null or empty in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, null, is-empty

I'm sure I've missed something here. With a certain project I need to check if a string is null or empty.

Is there an easier way of writing this?

```
if (myString == null || myString == "")
{
   ...
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, there's the [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) helper method for exactly this already:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: And on a relate note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552350/string-isnullorempty-check-for-space/2552381#2552381

Comment: Just to be super-clear, you _**need**_ to use the class function for `string/String`, *NOT* trying to use the function via the object! Eg, `String foo;` will not allow you to do `foo.IsNullOrEmpty();`; you need to use it like `String.IsNullOrEmpty(foo);` This is kind of annoying when coming from other languages that have built in null/0-length-checks for their string objects, since you can't safely do something like, `if(foo.Length == 0)` because that can trigger an exception.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: You should be able to use `if (foo?.Length ?? 0 == 0)`, but in general, calling an instance method requires a non-`null` reference. You can fake this with extension methods that don't check their argument, but I think that's frowned upon, as extension methods should behave as if they were instance methods.

Comment: That's some strange syntax o_o I'm not a C# developer, just someone who happens to use it once in a while to develop modules with it ad-hoc but I can't say I've seen anything like that before... I get what it's doing, just wished I knew about it sooner!

Answer (score 5):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)) {
  ...
}
```

Or you could take advantage of a quirk in extension methods, they allow *this* to be null:

```
static class Extensions {
    public static bool IsEmpty(this string s) {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s);
    }
}
```

which then lets you write:

```
if (myString.IsEmpty()) {
  ...
}
```

Although you probably should pick another name than 'empty'.

Comment: Nice example of extension methods! Thanks!

Comment: Why not `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)` instead of `s == null || s == string.Empty`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on .NET 4, you can use

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myString)){

}
```

else:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)){

}
```

Comment: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` checks for something else than being equal to `""` so it'd have different semantics than the code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid null checks you can use ?? operator.

```
var result = value ?? "";
```

I often use it as guards to avoid sending in data that I don't want in methods.

```
JoinStrings(value1 ?? "", value2 ?? "")
```

It can also be used to avoid unwanted formatting.

```
string ToString()
{
    return "[" + (value1 ?? 0.0) + ", " + (value2 ?? 0.0) + "]";
}
```

This can also be used in if statements, it's not so nice but can be handy sometimes.

```
if (value ?? "" != "") // Not the best example.
{
}
```

Comment: `??` can be used to avoid `null` check but not for `""`. `"" ?? anything"` still yeilds to `""`

Answer (score 1):

In c# 9 by using pattern matching you could do the following

```
myString is not {Length: > 0}; // Equivalent to string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)
```

Comment: Honestly? I don't like it.. "myString is not an object with a length property that is greater than zero" - this is a negative flavored test (like a test for success being `if(!operationFailed)` - negative flavored / `if(operationSucceeded)` - positive flavor). You have to stop and think about what it actually means/what the author intended so it reduces code readability/glanceability/self-documentation. `IsNullOrEmpty` does a really good job of explaining what it does.

Comment: It might be not so great for readability but it's a feature of the language now

Answer (score 1):

C# 9's pattern matching allows you to write:

```
myString is null or ""
```

Answer (score -2):

// if the string is not defined to null then **IsNullOrEmpty** it works great but if string is defined null then trim will throw exception.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString.Trim()){
 ...
}
```

//you can use **IsNullOrWhiteSpace** which work well for multiple white space in string .i.e it return true for multiple white space also

```
 if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (myString.Trim()){
     ...
    }
```

Comment: "Trim" is not a standalone function, it is an instance method of String. Proper usage: `myString.Trim()`, but that blows up when mystring is null. Use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Comment: i agree with you, so i have corrected in above code. Thanks @HansKesting