# How can I check whether a string variable is empty or null in C#?

Tags: c#, string, isnullorempty

How can I check whether a C# variable is an empty string `""` or null?

I am looking for the simplest way to do this check. I have a variable that can be equal to `""` or null. Is there a single function that can check if it's not `""` or null?

Comment: I specifically think you didn't explain this in-depth. You said `to "" or null`, then `not "" or null`, which was throwing me off.

Comment: The duplicate closure direction here should be reversed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626375/easier-way-of-writing-null-or-empty is phrased worse, has far fewer views, no better answers, and is younger than this question.

Answer (score 298, accepted):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)) {
   //
}
```

Comment: when i use  `IsEmpty` it says: `'string' does not contain a definition for IsEmpty` , can i use `IsEmpty` in [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.stringextensions.isempty%28v=vs.99%29.aspx)  or should i use `IsNullOrEmpty` ?

Comment: Very simple and useful. I wish PHP could have something like this

Comment: @Lion Liu: Actually I think PHP has exactly as much to offer. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: I like IsNullOrWhiteSpace (null,empty, or whitespace...)

Comment: @AndrewLiu there is you simple do if (empty($my_var))

Comment: Just to be super-clear, you have to use the class function for `string/String`, *NOT* trying to use the function via the object! Eg, `string foo;` will not allow you to do `foo.IsNullOrEmpty();`; you need to use it like `string.IsNullOrEmpty(foo);` This is kind of annoying when coming from other languages that have built in null/0-length-checks for their string objects.

Comment: `stom`, your question was unclear. You just said `IsEmpty`, but that is not a valid `variable` in the .NET C#

Answer (score 68):

Since .NET 2.0 you can use:

```
// Indicates whether the specified string is null or an Empty string.
string.IsNullOrEmpty(string value);
```

Additionally, since .NET 4.0 there's a new method that goes a bit farther:

```
// Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string value);
```

Answer (score 13):

if the variable is a string

```
bool result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(variableToTest);
```

if you only have an object which may or may not contain a string then

```
bool result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(variableToTest as string);
```

Comment: I had the same problem and the second one doesn't work correctly. Try this:
object x=3; bool result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(x as string);
'x as string' will be null so the result is true despite x having a value other than null or an empty string. I didn't find a short solution, used a double check.

Comment: @MártonMolnár it would have to contain a string 3 is not a string so this is expected try using "3" instead

Answer (score 3):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)) 
{
  . . .
  . . .
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`string.IsNullOrEmpty` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Cheap trick:

```
Convert.ToString((object)stringVar) == ""
```

This works because `Convert.ToString(object)` returns an empty string if `object` is null. `Convert.ToString(string)` returns null if `string` is null.

(Or, if you're using .NET 2.0 you could always using `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.)

Comment: While technically correct I can categorically say I have never seen this method used.

Comment: Are we to assume that this conversion of stringVar to a cast object returns empty string for both null and empty string assigned to the stringVar variable, but converting the same stringVar without the cast returns null and empty string instead? Im just trying to find out all the variations.....