# Throw an error when the user enter null or empty string

Tags: c#, .net, string, exception

I'm attempting to resolve the following exercise:

> You need to create a class named `Product` that represents a product.
>   The class has a single property named `Name`. Users of the `Product` class
>   should be able to get and set the value of the `Name` property. However,
>   any attempt to set the value of `Name` to an empty string or a null
>   value should raise an exception. Also, users of the `Product` class
>   should not be able to access any other data members of the `Product`
>   class. How will you create such a class?

I have created the following code but for some reason it does not throw the exception when the string is invalid:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Product newProduct = new Product();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Product name:");
        newProduct.Name = null; //Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Product name is : {0}", newProduct.Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Product
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (Name != String.Empty || Name != null)
            {
                name = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be null or empty string", "Name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is the exception not thrown because I do not have `try-catch` statement?
I was also wondering is it possible to have only catch statement without try statement?

Comment: You are checking previous value (which is valid). Use `value` instead of `Name` in `if` to validate new value. Or just try to set `Name` inside `Main` twice ;)

Comment: You cannot catch without try. Otherwise, how would it know what code that it is supposed to catch from? Even if you don't have a try/catch, exceptions still get thrown. You're just not reaching the code. Learn to use your IDE's debugging tools to step through the code line by line as it executes. I think you'll spot the issue fairly quickly that way.

Comment: You're using an `or` in your if statement. If `Name == null`, then `Name != String.Empty` and that part passes. Use `&&`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check a C# variable is an empty string "" or null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224700/how-can-i-check-a-c-sharp-variable-is-an-empty-string-or-null)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `if` state is wrong. Let's do a truth table:

```
if (value != String.Empty || value != null)
```

---

```
Name = null   True Or False  = True 
Name = "name" True Or True = True
Name = ""     False Or True = True
```

Your if statement is **always true**!

I would re-write it thus:

```
if (value == String.Empty || value == null)
{
     throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be null or empty string", "Name");  
}
else
{
     name = value;
}
```

---

you could just change the Or to and AND but I think the above reads better (the below has an unnecessary double negative):

```
if (value != String.Empty && value != null)
{
   name = value;
}
else
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be null or empty string", "value");
}
```

---

As Dmitry Bychenko says, I didn't notice you were not testing for `value`. [In getters you should use the `value` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx). Not the name of **your** property

---

The second parameter (again pointed out by Dmitry Bychenko) in your exception should be:

> The name of the parameter that caused the current exception.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxykka64(v=vs.110).aspx)

which in your case is the string `"value"`:

```
throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be null or empty string", "value");
```

Comment: Yes but syntactically it reads better to switch the statements. *Is the string empty **or** null then it's wrong*.

Comment: errh you should always compare against `!= null` first. It's just 'good practice' so you'll never do something like `if(x.Prop1 == "test" && x != null)`

Comment: But this is a value type....that isn't relevant here. That only applies to reference types.

Comment: @Liam: I'm very sorry for my impoliteness, but the incorrect comparison actually ruined all the work; now it's OK , so +1 from me (side note: update, please, `ArgumentException` as well: "value" in the text and "value" as the argument name)

Comment: this answer my question, but indeed I need to check the value not a Name, nonetheless it answered my question and explain why. I can also see it was edited. Thank you @Liam!

Comment: Sorry, @DmitryBychenko, not sure I follow you? Do you mean the second value in the Exception should be value (`throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be null or empty string", value);`). The one used seems [a valid override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxykka64(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: *"The name of the parameter that caused the current exception."*

Comment: @Liam: it should be `"value"` not `value`'s value but a string "value". It's parameter "value" provided by "set" causes the exception.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty Method (String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx). Change your `set` like this:

```
set
{
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
      {
            name = value;
      }
      else
      {
            throw new ArgumentException("Name cannot be null or empty string", "value");
      }
}
```

Also you can use [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace Method (String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) that Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

Answer (score 3):

If you want *different* exceptions on *null* and on *empty* string (often *null* means that something is *totally wrong*, when empty string is just a *format error*):

```
public string Name {
  get {
    return name;
  }
  set {
    if (null == value)
      throw new AgrumentNullException("value");
    else if (String.Equals(value, ""))
      throw new AgrumentException("Empty values are not allowed.", "value");

    name = value; 
  }
}
```

In case you don't want to *distiguish* them:

```
public string Name {
  get {
    return name;
  }
  set {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
      throw new AgrumentException("Null or empty values are not allowed.", "value");

    name = value; 
  }
}
```

Note, that in both cases it's `value` that you have to test, not a property `Name`. In your original code the `name`'s (and so `Name` as well) *initial value* is `null` and you'll get exception *whatever* you try to set.

Comment: this is only a simple exercise and I believe I can check for both null or empty string in the same exception, but it is a valid point you made and I will keep that in mind. Thanks.