# Check if password field is empty

Tags: c#, xaml

In my XAML I have:

```
<PasswordBox PlaceholderText="Password" Name="login_password" Width="350" />
```

Am trying to check if the `PasswordBox` is empty via:

```
if(login_password.Text == "") //this returns an error
{
    //show message box
}
```

How can I check if the `PasswordBox` is empty?

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: For password box it is `login_password.Password` not .Text

Answer (score 3):

The `PasswordBox` has the [`Password`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.password(v=vs.110).aspx) property. So you should check for `Password` property instead of `Text`:

```
if(login_password.Password == "")
```

Comment: When checking if a string has a value, you should use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(login_password.Password)`. This checks if the string is `null`, empty (`""`) or only contains whitespace characters, such as spaces or newlines

Comment: @JonStødle Good point. I'm agree with you and here is an example also https://stackoverflow.com/a/32631216/2946329