# how to remove empty strings from list object

Tags: c#, list

Before I set Url = r.Link I want to make sure r.link is not empty string?

> Would I be able to do that in this code snippet?

```
target.RelatedArtifact = template.References.Select(r => new RelatedArtifact()
            {
                Type = r == template.References.First() ? RelatedArtifact.RelatedArtifactType.DerivedFrom : RelatedArtifact.RelatedArtifactType.Citation,
                Display = StripHtml(r.Text).Replace(" .", ".").Replace(" ®", "®") /* Html stripping artifact in <em></em> */,
                Url = r.Link
            }).ToList();
```

Output

```
<relatedArtifact>
    <type value="citation" />
    <display value="sss, et al. ss. s;2(2):2." />
    <url value="" /> shouldn't have this tag?
</relatedArtifact>
```

Comment: And what if `r.Link` is an empty string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check a C# variable is an empty string "" or null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224700/how-can-i-check-a-c-sharp-variable-is-an-empty-string-or-null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simply, test r.Link and replace it with whatever you need if is null or  empty (or just white space, I assume)

```
target.RelatedArtifact = template.References.Select(r => new RelatedArtifact()
            {
                Type = r == template.References.First() ? RelatedArtifact.RelatedArtifactType.DerivedFrom : RelatedArtifact.RelatedArtifactType.Citation,
                Display = StripHtml(r.Text).Replace(" .", ".").Replace(" ®", "®") /* Html stripping artifact in <em></em> */,
                Url = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Link)? SOME_MEANINGFUL_VALUE : r.Link
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: If I set it then it will be in the output is there a way to do it and not set it to an object?

Comment: If by "it" you mean `Url`, you can replace `SOME_MEANINGFUL_VALUE` with `null`