# How do I validate a List<String> with char.IsDigit?

Tags: c#

I want to validate a List with char.IsDigit but some of the strings are empty / null which gives me the exception (System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. '), is there a way to bypass the empty cells and just validate the strings that has a value?

```
foreach (var item in accounts)
{
    if(item.Jan == null || !item.Jan.All(c => char.IsDigit(c)))
```

Comment: You already have `item.Jan == null`. Can you clarify why this isn't sufficient for your usecase?

Comment: Op code did include a null check before edit . .

Comment: Dupe target [How can I check a C# variable is an empty string “” or null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626375/easier-way-of-writing-null-or-empty)

Comment: I will recommend reading the [ask] and [mre] guide lines. Adding a little reproductible example that produce the error is always a good thing, like https://dotnetfiddle.net/VuKzUf . With a simple class and the initialisation. That way it will be clear if you have issue with Item null or item.Jan null.

Comment: Your title indicate you have issue when  item.Jan is null. Your question body also point in this sidrection. But your original code show that you already handle null, so it must be when item is null.

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach (var item in accounts.Where(acc => account != null))
{
    if ( item.Jan != null && item.Jan.All(c => char.IsDigit(c)))
    {
        //Do your stuff.
    }
}
```

should do the trick.