# Check if value exists. Equals(...) vs. patternMatching

Tags: c#

I want to check if a given object value is null or is an empty string. I got the following ideas:

```
...

public void Cmp1(object a) {
    if(a == null || Equals(a, string.Empty)) {
         Value = null;
         return;
    }
    ....
}


public void Cmp2(object a) {
    if(a == null || (a is string stringValue && string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))) {
         Value = null;
         return;
    }
    ....
}
```

Which one is better? Is Equals exposing some danger? Or `(a is string stringValue && string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))` is super slow?

Comment: You can simply use ```string.IsNullOrEmpty``` without the null-check .

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @imsmn With an `object`?

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626375/easier-way-of-writing-null-or-empty for the string check as imsmn said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the second option is you almost certainly want to use `stringValue` after the conditional block, meaning you must do the work a second time.

I might use the `as` operator, like this:

```
public void Cmp(object a)
{
    var stringValue = a as string;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue)) {
        Value = null; //this suggests the function should return something, instead of a void method
        return;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or I might negate the condition (and remove the `null` check):

```
public void Cmp(object a) {
    // pattern matching is still safe to use if `a` is null
    if(a is string stringValue && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue)) {
        // stringValue is in scope here
    }
    else {
        // but not here... but we no longer need it
        Value = null;
    }
}
```

If you don't intend to use `stringValue` again at all, I'd write it like this:

```
public void Cmp(object a)
{
    if (!(a is string) || string.IsNullOrEmpty((string) a)) {
        Value = null; 
        return;
    }
    // ...
}
```

But most of all... none of this is likely to drive the performance of your program. You're spending a bunch of time worrying about details that would be much better spent looking at profiler results, which can tell you exactly where to spend your time optimizing to make your app faster.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Is that mean that if I do not use this string later I should use "Equals(...)" approach?

Comment: No. When comparing with `string.Empty()` I always use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` or `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()`, even when I already know the string can't be null. Even when I use `Equals()`, I always use the form `a.Equals(b)`, rather than `Equals(a, b)`.

Comment: Your first code block isn't appropriate, since it will set `Value` to `null` if a is a `DateTime` for example (which the original code does not do). _Similarly, I think the other code samples have fundamentally the same bug._