# How can I Non-kludgily/tediously prevent the attempt to write empty strings to class members?

Tags: c#, string, generic-list, sharepoint-list, class-members

I've got a class that represents a Sharepoint List like this:

```
private class ListColumns
{
    public String li_requestDate { get; set; }
    public String li_paymentAmount { get; set; }
    public String li_payeeName { get; set; }
    public String li_remitAddressOrMailStop { get; set; }
    . . .
```

I read items that had previously been saved to the Sharepoint List like this:

```
private List<ListColumns> ReadFromList()
{
    List<ListColumns> lcList = new List<ListColumns>();

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
        {
            SPList list = web.Lists[listTitle];
            SPListItemCollection SpListColl = list.Items;
            foreach (SPListItem item in SpListColl)
            {
                ListColumns lc = new ListColumns();
                lc.li_requestDate = item["RequestDate"].ToString();
                lc.li_payeeName = item["PayeeName"].ToString();
                lc.li_remitAddressOrMailStop = item["RemitAddressOrMailStop"].ToString();
                . . .
```

This code crashes if a value being assigned to a class member is an empty string - IOW, attempts to assign an empty string to any of these class members results in ReadFromList()'s catch method acting as if a GOTO statement pointing to it had been reached (and that sans the ingathering of $200 -- or any amount, for that matter).

I can prevent this with kludgy/tedious code like so:

```
if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item["RequestDate"].ToString())))
{
    lc.li_requestDate = item["RequestDate"].ToString();
}
if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item["PayeeName"].ToString())))
{
    lc.li_payeeName = item["PayeeName"].ToString();
}
. . .
```

(etc. etc. ad nauseum ad finitum adwords with friends &c)

...but have an inkling there must be a "more better" way. Can anyone concretely corroborate my intuition?

### UPDATE

Trying Alex's code:

```
item.SetAsString("RequestDate", x => lc.li_requestDate = x);
```

I still get, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" if the value is empty.

MatteoSP's code:

```
Apply(item, "RequestDate", x => lc.li_requestDate = x);
```

...doesn't even compile; I get two err msgs:

*The best overloaded method match for 'DirectPaymentSectionsWebPart.DPSVisualWebPart.DPSVisualWebPartUserControl.Apply(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary, string, System.Action)' has some invalid arguments*

-and:

*Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary'*

### UPDATE 2

My kludgy/verbose code, which I thought would at least work:

```
if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item["RemitAddressOrMailStop"].ToString())))
{
    lc.li_remitAddressOrMailStop = item["RemitAddressOrMailStop"].ToString();
}
```

...also fails with the obtuse "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*" objection.

Will it be necessary to exalt Kludginess even higher by writing a " " (space) to every otherwise-would-be-empty value when writing to the List?

### UPDATE 3

I also tried the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552350/string-isnullorempty-check-for-space) posted by Shaw, but with the same old result (crash, with "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object*")

Comment: I updated my answer to include an additional `null` check, should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using an extension method

```
public static class ListItemExtensions
{
    public static void SetAsString(this SPListItem item, string colName, Action<string> destSetter)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            var col = item[colName];
            if (col != null)
            {
                var colVal = col.ToString();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(colVal))
                    destSetter(colVal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 item.SetAsString("RequestDate", x => lc.li_requestDate = x);
```

Comment: You can't pass properties by ref

Comment: @MatteoSp You are right, I had not looked at OPs input class well enough. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You could define this:

```
    static void Apply(IDictionary<string, object> dict, string key, Action<string> setter)
    {
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(key) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dict[key].ToString()))
            return;

        setter(dict[key].ToString());
    }
```

then use it this way:

```
Apply(item, "RequestDate", x => lc.li_requestDate = x);
Apply(item, "PayeeName", x => lc. li_payeeName = x);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, after handling the data with kid gloves.

The code that reads from the list is still like this:

```
if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item["RequestDate"].ToString())))
{
    lc.li_requestDate = item["RequestDate"].ToString();
}
```

...but the code that writes to the list has grown *really* belt and suspenderish, like this:

```
if (null != boxFundingApproverPrinted)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(boxFundingApproverPrinted.Text))
    {
        spli["FundingApproverName"] = "[left blank]";
    }
    else
    {
        spli["FundingApproverName"] = boxFundingApproverPrinted.Text;
    }
}
else
{
    spli["FundingApproverName"] = "[left blank]";
}
```

...admittedly, it's kludgious (kludgy and tedious), but it works...(I saw Alex's update after I had finished it all).